# Change element css class based on xml file value

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, xmlhttprequest

Is this even a possibility? Never attempted or tried anything like this before, I have no idea where to start.

I have a local file that when a manual button is pressed, it updates an xml file changing

```
<status>live<\status> 
to 
<status>killed<\status>
```

I also have a HTML page that has Iframes pulling live camera feeds for IP cameras. I want to hide the iframe and show a graphic instead when the status is ‘killed’.

Does anyone know if this is possible and where I’d start? Somehow check the xml file regularly or somehow know it has been updated.

Then somehow apply classes or introduce elements such as a div to mask the iframe.

Comment: can you provide more code of your html, are you getting the value injected anywhere in your html file? or its only updated on the xml, are you extracting the data from xml using ajax calls to that xml?I believe more explanation will help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can work with XML in JavaScript almost the same as if you were working with HTML. However, without a server-side component, writing the xml document back to the file system will not be possible. You can always download it for the user, but you can't write directly to the file system.

Here's a simple example of updating an XML document with JS. I put both the string of xml and the logic to parse string into an xml doc in the example since I'm not sure what your setup is.

```js
const xmlString = `
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
`;
const xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString, 'text/xml');

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const to = xmlDoc.querySelector('note to');
  to.innerHTML = 'Someone New';
  console.log('The TO field is now ', xmlDoc.querySelector('note to').innerHTML);
  
  // Set HTML Element from XML
  const h1 = document.getElementById('fromXml');
  h1.innerText = xmlDoc.querySelector('note heading').innerHTML;
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Set To</button>
<h1 id="fromXml"></h1>
```

Comment: Is it possible to go the other way? And read from the xml file and introduce an element to the HTML page based on the xml value? So basically a value in the xml file changes from yes to no, and based on that show or hide an element in the HTML file

Comment: Yea, that's possible. You would just create the element and append it to your container. Please upvote/mark as answer

Comment: Sorry this is alien to me, what would that look like?

Comment: I updated the snippet to demonstrate how to set an html element from a value in an xml file. Please mark as answer/upvote